# Apache 2.2.15を、2.2系の最新へアップグレードしたいがうまくいかない

Tags: centos, apache, yum

**環境**
・CentOS 6.8

> # httpd -v

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

---

**試したこと**

> # cat /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.alt.ru.repo

```
[CentALT]
name=CentALT Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/6/$basearch/
#baseurl=http://mirror.sysadminguide.net/centalt/repository/centos/6/$basearch/
#baseurl=http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0
```

> cat /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo

・esplは以前導入していました
・ネットの情報を見て、[epel]部分だけ書き換えました

```
[epel]
name=EPEL RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux
baseurl=http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/fedora/epel/6/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0

#[epel]
#name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
#mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
#failovermethod=priority
#enabled=1
#gpgcheck=1
#gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
```

---

**この状態でアップデートしたのですが、**

> yum --enablerepo=CentALT --skip-broken update httpd

```
更新と設定されたパッケージがありません
```

**確認しても変化はありませんでした**

> # httpd -v

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

---

**下記で検索しても、httpd-2.2.23などが表示されないのはナゼでしょうか？**
・CentALTが認識されていない？
・あるいは、以前導入していたepelがおかしい？？

> yum list --enablerepo=CentALT | grep httpd | grep CentALT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

すべてのリポジトリで常に最新のパッケージが配布されているわけでは無いので、参照したリポジトリに必要なパッケージ(バージョン)が存在しない場合もあります。

有効になっているリポジトリを確認するにはrepolistオプションを指定します。

```
# yum repolist
```

リポジトリの情報はメタデータという形でローカルに保存されているので、設定変更の直後等はキャッシュを削除することで最新のデータに更新することができます。

```
# yum clean all
# yum check-update
```

上記を踏まえた上で、`yum list httpd`を実行しても"更新と設定されたパッケージがありません"と出るならCentALTには既にシステムにインストールしているものとバージョンが同じか、もしくはもっと古いバージョンのパッケージしか用意されていないのではないでしょうか。

---

余談ですが、CentALTリポジトリにブラウザからアクセスすると私の環境(firefox)では危険なサイトとしてブロックされるので、実際のファイルは確認していません。

---

2.2系を最新版にアップグレードする代替案としては

- 公式サイトからソースコードをダウンロードしてコンパイル
- 公式サイトからソースコードをダウンロードして自分でrpmパッケージを作成(rpmbuild)
- 他のリポジトリを探してみる (例:[RPM Search](http://rpm.pbone.net/), [rpmseek](http://www.rpmseek.com/))

などになるかと思います(なるべく信頼できる配布元から入手することをお勧めします)。

Apache公式で配布されているアーカイブ(tar.gz)にはspecファイルが含まれていたので、比較的簡単にrpmパッケージを作成できる可能性があります。

```
# rpmbuild -ta httpd-2.2.34.tar.gz
```

参考: [tarボールからRPMファイルを作成するには](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/flinux/rensai/linuxtips/486mkrpmfromtar.html)

Comment: 「yum list --enablerepo=CentALT | grep httpd」と打ったら「httpd24」がたくさん出てきました。もしかすると新し過ぎて(2.4系の最新が同梱されているだけで)、2.2系はもうないのかな、と思いました。例えばですが、2.2系の最新が同梱されているリポジトリを探すことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 回答中に記載したrpmパッケージの検索サイトで探せばいくつか見つかりますので、お使いのシステム(OSバージョンや32bit/64bit)に合ったパッケージをダウンロード、rpmコマンドでインストール/アップグレードすることは可能だと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。それでは探してみたいと思います

Answer (score 1):

> 下記で検索しても、httpd-2.2.23などが表示されないのはナゼでしょうか？

1. CentOSはRHELに追従する形でパッケージングを行いますので Centos6 での httpd の最新は 2.2.15 です。
2. CentALT はよく分かりませんが、HTTPレスポンスを見ると404NotFoundになりましたのでリポジトリ自体が削除されたのではと推測します。
3. epel には httpd のパッケージはありません。

Yumのリポジトリは公式／非公式なもの含めるとたくさんありますので、探してみるといいかもしれません。
https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

ただ、その労力を考えるとソースコードからビルドして自前でRPMパッケージを作ったほうが楽なような気がします…。

Comment: 自前でRPMパッケージを作ったことはないのですが、探すよりも簡単ならその方法も検討してみたいと思います